# Creating Tensors from features that are linked together

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-transform

I have a set of multi valued features which are linked together. As an example,

| ItemCodes | Scores |
| --- | --- |
| AK, NA, UY | 0.6, 0.2, 0.2 |
| KG, AK | 0.5, 0.5 |

Each Item has a corresponding score associated with it. Some rows might not have any items/scores. I want to convert this dataset (there are other numerical features) into a form that can be fed to an Neural Net. The data comes from a different part of the system with its own API.

I was trying to create a vector of item codes (binary, if the item is present or not) and a second vector with score values at the corresponding indices. If I only had Item codes, I could do a multi-hot encoding and get a feature vector of items. So far I am using

```
values = tft.compute_and_apply_vocabulary(itemcodes)
```

to get the indices, which I can then set to 1 in the output Tensor. But, if item **AK** is allotted index **j** in the multi-hot Tensor, how do I ensure **0.6** is also set at index **j** in the second Tensor? Because there can be missing values, the ItemCodes are Scores are available as a SparseTensor and so I am unable to iterate directly. How can I achieve what I want? Or is there a better way to represent such features?